# How to find 301/302 redirect source?

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, redirect, seo

here's the problem:
I got a site and I know it's target of a 301/302 redirect. Is it possible to find the source (the site that has redirecting headers) and how?

Answer (score 1):

The server's web logs usually list the [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) they received from the browser.  Check there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your target php code to figure our referrer.